# Regular Expression with a minus sign for negative values and leading zeroes for positive values

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

Ok, so I have a weird requirement for form validation using regex,

the range of values can be integers between -168 and 10688,

with the minus sign for negative values ranging from -168 to 10688.

The tricky part here is that for all the positive values, users always have to use leading

zeros with 4 char requirement for negative values and 5 chars for positive values

so for example: -023 is valid and 00000 and 00345 is valid. 0, 000, -000 is not valid.

How can this be implemented in regex? would this be too complicated?

please help! ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you

```
^(\d{5}|\-(?!000)\d{3})$
```

Akxe is correct about the max and min values acceptable. RegEx is only for string validation, hence it doesn't allow for math functions. You would have to validate that either client side with JavaScript or server side.

Comment: I am actually also doing the regex client side using angularjs, I think adding min="" max="" attributes to the input tag (and use input type="number") should do the trick along with your cleaner version of the regex....thanks for the help!!

Comment: Not a problem. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

This pattern should match your description:

```
(-[1-9]\d\d|-\d[1-9]\d|-\d\d[1-9]|\d{5})
```

Excluding `-000` is what makes this tricky, so you end up with 4 cases:

```
-[1-9]\d\d # negative numbers that have a non-zero digit in the first place
-\d[1-9]\d # negative numbers that have a non-zero digit in the second place
-\d\d[1-9] # negative numbers that have a non-zero digit in the third place
\d{5} # all positive numbers with exactly 5 digits
```

This pattern will not check for upper / lower bounds though, as that would be trivial with any programming language and isn't really the goal for a regular expression.

Comment: This also matches all values greater than 10680.... the range i'm looking for is between -168 and 10680...

Comment: Why would it be trivial for a programming language to check for upper/lower bounds? I see this is not useful for regex but is it even possible?

Comment: Sure it's possible, but then you'd end up with a regex pattern that's 4 times as long, barely comprehensible and really hard to change if you decide that your _new_ upper bound should be 23456, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
(-|[0-9]{2})[0-9]{3}
```

Details:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]{3}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (3 times)
```

Comment: "-023 is valid" - but won't be with this pattern. o_O

Comment: Sorry this matches many of the values that are out of the range of acceptable values...can't be [0-9]{4} because that'll match everything greater than 10688 to name one thing...thanks though

Comment: Ehh. I focused only the number format part. I think for min/max regular expression are not the best tools. Why don't you add min="" max="" attributes to the input tag (and use input type="number")?

Comment: Yea..I think adding min="" max="" attributes to the input tag (and use input type="number") should do the trick along with Bryan's cleaner version of the regex....thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

S.B.' answer (`(-[1-9]\d\d|-\d[1-9]\d|-\d\d[1-9]|\d{5})`) is correct, but you might still look at the fact that you have to add the `min` and `max` attributes to the input.
And for user ease while using your app you might want to add the leading zeros yourself, just a note.
PS.: What have this to do with angular?

Comment: i thought i would throw it in there since i'm using angularjs for front end....using ng-pattern